# Curl and Variables inside http

Tags: bash, variables, curl

I try to do combination of variable source and destination IP.
then I would like to send to our software to tell me if traffic is allow or not.
I am using curl  but I dont know how to add variables there

I need someting like this

```
curl -ks -X GET 'https://tufin.com/api/path?$line_source$line_destination$line_port
```

but this show me is not variable

---

```
line_source="$(cat $HOME/src)"

line_destination="$(cat $HOME/dst)"

line_port="$(cat $HOME/port)"


prepare_curl=$(echo -e "'https://tufin.com/api/path?src=$line_source&dst=$line_destination&service=$line_port'

result=$(curl -k -s   -X GET $prepare_curl )

echo -e " source $line_source  destination $line_destination   port $line_port   traffic is  $result"
```

```
curl: option -m: expected a proper numerical parameter
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the exact command that you're running?

Comment: `${variable}` while keeping the braces?

Comment: for curl I just put starting commnad the command continue with authentication etc and braces I have also tried result=$(curl -k -s   -X GET ${prepare_curl} )
 but no works

Comment: @sundrys1 This didn't work? `curl -k -s -X GET 'https://tufin.com/api/path?${line_source}${line_destination}${line_port}`